# Repeat Frequency Of Array Elements C Language

Tags: c, arrays, element, frequency

I've written a code that gets the frequency of some array entered by user.
but it prints the elements over and over again ( equal to the frequency )
what can I do about it?
Thanks
This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int n,i,j,count = 0;
printf("\n\n    Please Enter The Length Of Your Array : ");
scanf("%d",&n);
int array[n];
for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
    printf("    Please Enter The Index %d Element Of The Array : ", i );
    scanf("%d",&array[i]);
}
printf("\n        index        Element       Repeat Frequency     \n-----------------------------------------------------------");
for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ ) {
        if ( array[i] == array[j] ) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("\n        %3d             %3d             %3d     \n",i,array[i],count);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------");
    count = 0;
}
printf("\n\n\n");
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create another array and store the values which are already printed. Before printing check if the value is present in the second array.

Comment: Create another array called `used`. Whenever the inner `for(j...)` loop finds a repeated entry, set the corresponding entry in the `used` array to true. In the outer `for(i...)` loop, skip entries that have already been used.

Comment: Can you give me more details please?

Comment: `for (i...) { if (!used[i]) { for (j...) { if (...) { count++; used[j]=1; }`

Comment: I simply don't get it :| sorry :|